# Stopping Amazon Cloudwatch when using CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-code-deploy

When applying a deployment in AWS CodeDeploy is it necessary to shutdown Amazon CloudWatch during the ApplicationStop script phase and restart it after deployment during ApplicationStart?

Comment: What do you mean by "shutdown" CloudWatch? Are you talking about your own code that sends Custom Metrics? Normally, CloudWatch is automatic and can't be stopped.

Comment: Shutdown as in `sudo service awslogs stop` in a script run before the deployment phase.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to shutdown the CloudWatch agent when you run a deployment.